# How to download a pdf file from project folder in java

Tags: jsp, servlets, pdf

In my task i have to download a file which will be in my project folder it is working without using servlet i mean when i am using normal java class its working but when i am making it servlet its not working please anyone help me out here.. here is my code and SalarySlip is a folder in my project which is I have created manually ..

I have updated error message

```
   public class main extends HttpServlet
     {
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
  {
  try

     {

      Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream("D:/test/ReadPdf.pdf"));
        document.open();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("SalarySlip/pivot.pdf");
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        // Go through all pages
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          // only page number 2 will be included

            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
            document.add(instance);

        }
        document.close();

          }

  catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

    } 
   <body>
  <form name = "form" method="get" action="main">
   <input type="submit" value="login" >
  </body>
```

The error message showing:

```
   New/pivot.pdf not found as file or resource.
    at  com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.
      createByReadingToMemory(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:248)
          at  com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.
      createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:173)
      at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
   at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
   at com.journaldev.servlet.main.doGet(main.java:63)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.         internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
   .doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.
  invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.
    invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.
   AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
 .process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.
   process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: its not working???????wat error do u get..

Comment: I have updated error message you can check just folder name is diff remaining thing are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BeforeTest
     public void StartBrowser() {
      //Create object of FirefoxProfile in built class to access Its properties.
      FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();

```
  //Set Location to store files after downloading.


  // this one is working 
  fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\malik\\Desktop\\workspace\\payment\\CSVDownload");
```

**But in need to download on project folder like this**

fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","..\CSVDownload\");

**Like this i don't know what i do worng**

```
  fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);


  //Set Preference to not show file download confirmation dialogue using MIME types Of different file extension types.
  fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"//MIME types Of MS Excel File.
    + "application/pdf;" //MIME types Of PDF File.
    + "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;" //MIME types Of MS doc File.
    + "text/plain;" //MIME types Of text File.
    + "text/csv"); //MIME types Of CSV File.
  fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
  fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
  //Pass fprofile parameter In webdriver to use preferences to download file.
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);  
 }


 @Test
 public void OpenURL() throws InterruptedException{
  driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/05/login.html");

   //Download CSV File
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Download CSV File')]")).click();
  Thread.sleep(1000);

 }

 @AfterTest
 public void CloseBrowser() {  
  //driver.quit();  
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems to be wrong here

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("SalarySlip/pivot.pdf");
```

Change it to

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("../SalarySlip/pivot.pdf");
```

if its in the WEB-CONTENT folder

Comment: no its not working i kept file all the possible places in project in webcontent and other places too but its not working

Comment: @sourav78611 New is your folder right which is under webcontent?

Comment: right sir i can give u screenshot if u need @Santino 'Sonny' Corleone

Comment: wud be better if u could @sourav78611

Comment: k forget ...@sourav78611 i will help u out without dat

Comment: k sir i am waiting.. i am surprise because this thing i worked before but not with pdf file and same file working when i am using main method that java simple class.. and here i am using i-text concept..

Comment: System.outprintln( getServletContext().getRealPath("/")); what do u get?

Comment: @sourav78611 this should mostly work for u `String path=application.getRealPath("/New/pivot.pdf");` and put the path variable in your PdfReader

Comment: sir when i am giving like String path=application.getRealPath("/New/pivot.pdf"); declaration it is showing error for application so i am unable to create this variable.

Comment: sir help me on this.. I am waiting i stopped this work i was doing something but now i want to finish this task so please reply..

Answer (score 0):

```
       String INPUTFILE =  "/Salary/pivot.pdf";
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getServletContext().getRealPath(INPUTFILE));
```

it is working